# Sitecore Overriding Content Tree

Tags: events, treeview, sitecore, pipeline, sitecore7.2

Can't seem to to find this posted online anywhere - excuse me if it is!

I am looking for an event/pipeline that one can override for the main content tree in the CMS. I need to hide/disable items in the tree according to user roles so they will not be able to select or view them.

Thanks!
Dan

Comment: use access right? break inheritance of read/write for chosen role/user

Answer (score 4):

You should be using access rights for it. It would fit your needs.

You basically need to select the item you need to limit access, then got to the Security>Assign.
Break inheritance to Everyone, then set Allow Read for a specifc role you want to allow. That will hide the items in the tree for the users which are not in the specified role.

Comment: I need to filter the content tree itself - i can use read access through roles but due to it being a large website/content tree i was wondering if there is a way to filter the items shown!

Comment: Daniel,  When you remove read access to a content item it should no longer be displayed in the content tree for that role/user.  Are you not seeing this behavior when setting the access rights?

Comment: Yes i am; but this is going to be content items that users will be adding dynamically. Example: Content Node called Consultants will list all Consultant but Hospital X Staff can only see Consultant A, B and C while Hospital Y can only see Consultant D.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are situations where access filtering might not be a very good solution, so you should probably go with a custom DataView instead. Override the default Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.MasterDataView class and override the GetChildItems like this:

```
protected override void GetChildItems (ItemCollection children, Item parent)
{
    base.GetChildItems(children, parent);
    YourFilteringMethod(children); // Let this method remove unwanted items
}
```

Then replace the master data view in your sitecore config file, such as using a patch file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:x="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
   <dataviews>
      <dataview name="Master">
        <patch:attribute name="assembly">YourAssembly</patch:attribute>
        <patch:attribute name="type">YourNamespace.MasterDataView</patch:attribute>
      </dataview>
    </dataviews>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Here's a post about it where it's being used for language filtering (it goes a bit further as well), but you can implement it for doing access filtering that suits your needs instead:

http://mikael.com/2014/10/sitecore-dataviews/

/ Mikael

Comment: Hi @mikaelnet, thanks for this - very helpful! Trying it out but can't seem to hook the event correctly after adding the config patch. Any suggestions what to look at? I have not added the 'Untranslated items' checkbox functionality cause i already have a field to check up on.

Comment: Hi Daniel! Is the patch config applied correctly? Do you see that it is replacing the Master data view? I updated the config patch above with a complete file. The checkbox part is not needed, so you can leave that out as you described.